# Can you sort products by price, starting with the most expensive. in magento

Tags: magento, search

How would you go about sorting products with the most expensive first?

I currently have it set to sort by price but it starts with cheapest and works its way up. Is there a way to have it the other way around?

Answer (score 2):

Magento currently doesn't let you define the sort order from the backend configuration. They let you choose what you can sort by, however. To change the default sort order, you must do the following:

1. Copy `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php`
2. Open `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php`
3. Look for `protected $_direction = 'asc';`
4. Change to `protected $_direction = 'desc';`
5. Save the file, clear caches.

To change the default sort by to Price, do the following:

1. In the Magento Admin, Go to System > Configuration > Catalog
2. Change Product Listing Sort by to Price
3. Click Save Config